# How to configure client applications?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, adal

I have two applications (ui and api) in Azure Active Directory. How do I add ui application id to knownClientApplications list in api application manifest via PowerShell script?

Comment: Could you include additional details like what you tried and where you stuck with code and errors by editing your question?

Comment: Currently I added the id manually. But I would like to add it automatically via a script.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one App registration named `API App` like below:

[image]

Now, I registered one Azure AD registration named `UI App` like below:

[image]

To add this `UI App` application id to knownClientApplications list in `API App` application manifest via PowerShell, you can use below script:

```
$UIAppId = "c94e5f5f-c2b6-4a14-82a4-xxxxxxx"
$API0bjectId = "861f810d-a48f-4cb0-9b71-xxxxxxxx"

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $API0bjectId -KnownClientApplications $UIAppId
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, `UI App` ID added successfully to **knownClientApplications** list in `API App` application manifest like below:

[image]

If you want to set **Authorized client applications** from PowerShell, you can refer below link:

[How do you set preAuthorizedApplications using Powershell by **SaurabhSharma-MSFT**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/56214#issuecomment-638449476)

Comment: Why did you expose an API in API App? Plmk.

Comment: I ran the script without exposing the API and added known client applications. Please check the updated answer.